# Eclipse easy way to refactor project to use a different class

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen and right now I have a Java project that uses a Utility class from a JAR file.  I would like to remove this JAR file from the project but doing this generates about 500 errors, as expected since the Utility class will also no longer in classpath.

The idea is for main project to reference a new Utility class from another JAR.  Is  there an easy way to tell Eclipse to automatically change the references from old Utility class to the new one?  The class name will be the same Utility but the package name of the new Utility class will be different.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to do a textual search/replace of the affected import statements.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the **source folder** create a **copy** of the utility class of the old JAR
2. **Move** the copied utility class to the new package
3. **Delete** the moved copied utility class and in the Java Build Path replace the old JAR with the new JAR